# Etymology of 'connex' and 'transitive' for binary relations

Tags: terminology, relations

There is a great question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504195/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-term-reflexive-in-the-context-of-binary-relations) about the etymology behind the term 'reflexive' for binary relations. How about
'connex' and 'transitive'? Where do these names come from?

I expect that transitivity is related to the idea of transitive verbs in grammar based on the etymology for reflexivity, but I can't see the relation exactly.  Connex I have no idea about, it looks kind of like convex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mathematical meaning of *connex* is a new use of an obsolete English adjective meaning ‘connected’, for which the OED has citations from 1653, 1677, and 1685. It is derived from Latin *connexus*, classical Latin *cōnexus*, the past participle of *connectō*. The idea is that a connex order is ‘connected’ in the sense that no two elements are incomparable.

The mathematical sense of *transitive* goes back at least to De Morgan; the OED has a citation from 1856 for him. The word derives from Latin *transeō* ‘to pass over’; the idea is that the relationship makes a transition through the intermediate term.

Comment: Interesting. But I don't remember coming across the word even once over the period 1970 Iwhen I completed the undergraduate math syllabus) until maybe the last few years. Is it really in common use? Why is it useful? Do we really need it?

Comment: @almagest: My experience is similar: I was an undergraduate in the 1960s, and I first encountered the term here within the last few years. If my experience here is anything to go by, it’s probably becoming increasingly common, though the Wikipedia article suggests that usage is still somewhat mixed. I think that it probably is handy to have a term for a relation without completely unrelated elements, and it does have the virtue of suggesting its mathematical meaning.